# any new technology for C# gui framework from MS?

Tags: c#, user-interface

some backgroud info first:
I worked on MFC for 5 years and then c#(winform) for 1 year and then switched to embedded world (pure c). After 2 years now I got a new job and I must switch back to .net framework for some hmi software(SCADA).
I guess I haved missed the wpf thing that MS promoted a lot several years ago, which is good because I heard it's already abandoned by MS, lucky me.

The HMI will be developed on .net framework, since I used c# before, I decided to keep that as the main programming language, although the existing code is in VB.

Now comes my question, if I'm going to develop an hmi, is winform(c#) still a good choise? Are there any new technology that is being promoted? I heard something like xaml? or maybe my knowledge is too outdated.

I have 2 points in my mind: use the technoledge which improves the efficiency, and don't be fooled by MS.

thanks

Comment: My crystal ball is defragging. I can share that WPF uses XAML, though.

Comment: The only thing dying in WPF is the name, after all WPF is nothing but XAML for HMI and C# for code behind and neither of those are dying.

Comment: Can WPF work together with Winform? because the existing code is using winform, can I plan to add wpf things little by little?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

XAML is the backbone of MS from a UI stance. WPF, Silverlight, and the forthcoming technologies around Windows 8 will all leverage XAML.

WPF is not dead, nor is Silverlight. They will exist in the LOB world for years to come. Choose one of those and move forward in confidence.

Comment: "...the forthcoming technologies around Windows 8 will all leverage XAML" not entirely true, HTML5 will be considered a native Windows development platform in Win8, and I wouldn't consider that to be leveraging XAML. But overall I agree, WPF (and Silverlight) have not been abandoned, and will continue to be supported and see new functionality added.

Answer (score 2):

Xaml and WPF are synonymous as Xaml (here's a [good Xaml overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752059.aspx) from MS) is used to write the look and feel of a WPF application. It's also used for Silverlight applications, so it's handy to know for desktop apps with Microsoft as those are two technologies that are newer.  There's no road map yet beyond Silverlight 5, but at the worse case Xaml is great to learn for everything else that they use.

As for other options, Windows 8 will see a push for HTML/JavaScript/CSS to create the Metro style apps. If that's not your target audience, then that's not a good option for you. If it is there are a lot of samples on the [Windows Dev Center under Windows 8 Metro Apps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/).

If you're comfortable with winform, stick with it; otherwise, I would pick up WPF or Silverlight as they will continue to be pushed more going forward into the future.

Comment: but winform is dead, am I right? (when I say winform is 'dead', I mean it's dead as MFC is 'dead': still alive but not the one with all promotions)

Comment: Yeah, I would consider it a deadend going forward.